# Ember model stays in "inFlight" state after 409 response from server using JSON API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am in the process of upgrading Ember and Ember Data to 1.13.x. I switched to using the new JSON API adapter/serializer and also changed the server response to conform the JSON API format. However I am having problem with an error handling scenario. A model gets properly updated when following the happy path but when the update needs to fail because say optimistic lock detects simultaneous updates then I have the model stuck in "inFlight" state.

This is an example request:

```
{
  data: {
    id: "1",
    type: "books",
    attributes: {
      name: "New Book Name",
      version: 1
    }
  }
}
```

The server finds out that the current version is greater than 1 and rejects the update with 409 HTTP status code and the response is:

```
{
  errors: [{
    code: "2",
    detail: "Simultaneous changes.",
    source: { 
      pointer: "data" 
    },
    status: "409"
  }]
}
```

The problem is that after the server response my model is in "root.loaded.updated.inFlight" state.
Even after calling model.rollbackAttributes() the state doesn't change.

Is this a problem in the server response JSON? Is this a bug in Ember Data?

Feedback is appreciated.

Comment: A few follow up questions. Are you using the RESTAdapter? Did this work in older versions of Ember/Ember Data (if so, which ones)? Does this only happen with 409, or do other error codes trigger this as well?

Comment: I use the new JSONAPIAdapter/Serializer. This wasn't an issue with the older Ember version. I haven't tested other error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like overriding "handleResponse" in JSONAPIAdapter is causing the issue. More specifically returning `new DS.InvalidError(payload.errors)` object from "handleResponse".

I override handleResponse following the pattern given in the migration guide - http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_new-errors-api

Not overriding "handleResponse" solves the problem.

I tried creating a JSBin to report this as a bug but I am having problems setting up a JSONAPIAdapter (where to override "handleResponse") in JSBin. If someone has handy JSBin which explicitly sets up JSONAPIAdapter please share the link. I could clone and tweak it to demonstrate the issue.